# Sharing violation on path in c# (for xamarin.ios)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am developing xamarin.ios  application and it worked well before two three months without any problem. But right now I am getting the below error occasionally.

“ Sharing violation on path /Users/vofox3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A357B468-BDBA-4397-B2D7-40A6333E93CD/data/Containers/Data/Application/5D715BAA-DD43-404D-8D94-0E11224745E8/Documents/WBidMax/User.xml”.

I am using below code to read the User.XML file.

```
/// <summary>
      /// Load configuration details from XML
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
      /// <param name="filePath"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string filePath)
      {
          try
          {

              T wBidConfiguration;
              using (TextReader configurationFileStream = new StreamReader(filePath))
              {
                  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                  wBidConfiguration = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(configurationFileStream);
                  return wBidConfiguration;
              }


          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              throw;
          }
      }
```

The below code  I am using to write the XML file.

```
public static bool SerializeToXml<T>(T configType, string filePath)
       {
           bool status = false;
           try
           {
               XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings;
               XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNamespaces;

               xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
               {
                   Indent = true,
                   OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                   NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
                   Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
                   CloseOutput = true


               };
               xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
               xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("", "");

               if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

               using (FileStream configurationFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
               {

                   using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(configurationFileStream, xmlWriterSettings))
                   {
                       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                       serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, configType, xmlSerializerNamespaces);
                   }
               }

               status = true;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               status = false;
           }

           return status;
       }
```

Could you please tell me the reason for this Error?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there is concurrent file access happening. Locking the file during write operations might fix this for you. Especially if you are accessing the file from different threads or tasks.